Creating a Bitcoin Payment Gateway with Electrum and python
I am trying to create a PayPal-like payment gateway for a web app developed with Django. I checked the Bitcoin website and took help from the wallet suggestion and installed Electrum according to my conditions. I searched the Electrum documentation for creating a payment gateway, but all of it is based on Electrum commands and I don't know how to execute these commands in my Python script. My main question is, is it possible to create a Bitcoin payment gateway on the Python platform? If so, do you know a solution that is as Pythonic as possible, for example with the requests library, or the Electrum library? I appreciate your valuable help in advance.

Is your goal to have a self-hosted payment processor or is your goal to build one? Are you aware of BTCPay Server?

I am new to programming so my goal is to choose a method that is simple, understandable and easy to implement. I am not familiar with BTCPay Server. Is there something similar to Electrum commands that can be used to create and send transactions to the network using a Python script? Does it provide me with servers like Electrum servers or a full node so I can run my queries?

You didn’t respond to my question. If you just want to have a payment processor to use, you can set up BTCPay Server and integrate it into your website. If you are new to programming and want to write your own payment processing software, I would recommend that you might aim for a slightly less ambitious goal first.
